# can I revert reset --hard of uncommitted changes in git

Tags: git

So i just started using GIT and i want to know if i can get back my uncommitted changes.

Here is what happen: I was working on a "local master" and made some changes. I tried to push on server master then i realize some one else made a change in one of the file i was working on that is why i got an conflict error. So i created a local branch named 'temp-client' from my local master, thinking i have my changes in branch. Then i ran two commands

```
git fetch -all
git reset --hard origin/master
```

but i did not commit any changes on my branch thinking it will stay there because i thought it will just force overwrite on master. Now i dont see my changes on my branch 'temp-client'. Is there any way to get back the uncommitted changes on my branch so i can fix the conflict and merge it back with Master?

Comment: no, sorry.  reset is an operation on the working tree and index.  --hard means 'I know it will delete my work, do it anyway'.  So it did.

Comment: Darn it! Well something you have to learn a hard way.i will keep that in mind from now. Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No; those are gone and lost forever.  Remember that Git's strength lies in keeping track of the changes that you've made.  If you don't inform Git of your changes in some way (at the bare minimum by staging the file), it is powerless to help you.

Comment: True that. Note that if you had committed your changes but reset your branch, the commit is then hanging in space without any branch pointer pointing at it. But in this case you can still recover these "lost" commits as explained here: http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/01/17/restoring-lost-commits.html Usually, if I'm going to nuke something i always `git commit -m "For safety, do not push"` so that my current workspace is saved. (I can then "cancel" the commit with `git reset --soft HEAD~1`)